# certainty equivalent and lotteries

Tags: microeconomics, utility, expected-utility, risk-aversion, uncertainty

suppose an agent has $u(z)=-e^{-bz}$ where $b>0$ as her Bernoulli utility function and faces two gambles:
G1: win 1000 dollars with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and zero with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and his certainty equivalent is 488 dollars
G2: win 1500 dollars with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and 500 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$
Question is : what can we say about his certainty equivalent for gamble2?
How can I approach this problem?

Comment: "I tried to derive his certainty equivalent by plugging numbers but I could not find it." -- How exactly did you try? What formula did you plug the numbers in?

Comment: Thanks fpr response. After you said I tried again and found 988 as certainty equivalent. How can I relate this to absolute risk aversion and relative risk aversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have an income of $z$ and receive an additional $x_i$ with probability $\pi_i$. Then the certainty equivalent $c_1$ is implicity defined by:
$$
\sum_i \pi_i u(z+x_i) = u(z+c)
$$
If we use the CARA utility function this gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_i \pi_i (-\exp(-b(z + x_i))) = (-\exp(-b (z + c_1))\\
\leftrightarrow &\sum_i \pi_i \exp(-b(z + x_i)) = \exp(-b (z + c_1) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
$$
Now consider a lottery where at every state $i$ you receive an additional amount $g$ then the certainty equivalent $c_2$ is given by:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_i \pi_i (-\exp(-b(z + g+ x_i))) = (-\exp(-b (z + c_2)),\\
\leftrightarrow &\sum_i \pi_i \exp(-b(z + g+ x_i)) = \exp(-b (z + c_2)
\end{align*}
$$
Using the properties of the exponential and using $(1)$, we can rewrite this as:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\exp(-bg)  \sum_i \pi_i \exp(-b(z +x_i)) = \exp(-b (z + c_2),\\
\leftrightarrow &\exp(-bg) \exp(-b(z + c_1) = \exp(-b(z + c_2)),\\
\leftrightarrow & \exp(-b(g + z + c_1 - z - c_2) = 1,\\
\leftrightarrow & \exp(-b(g + c_1 - c_2) = 1,\\
\to & c_1 + g = c_2.
\end{align*}
$$

This shows that if the mean of a lottery increases by an amount $g$ (by adding to every state the same amount) then the certainty equivalence increases by the same amount.